# Audience and Scope changed after adding Sites.Read.All

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAD login in my application and I have added `Sites.Read.All` to access SharePoint data via Microsoft Graph APIs in my scope and all of a sudden my audience and scope in my JWT token changed.

I require my old audience and scope and that should work with microsoft graph API

OLD login payload

```js
    issuer: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/7xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxd5/v2.0',
    clientId: '83xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxbb',
    redirectUrl: 'msauth.com.application.redirect://auth/',
    additionalParameters: { prompt: 'login' },
    scopes: [
        'openid',
        'profile',
        'email',
        'offline_access',
        'api://8xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxb/application.read', //audience scope
    ],
    androidAllowCustomBrowsers: ['chrome'],
```

OLD JWT Token decode

```
"aud": "api://8xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxbb",
"scp": "application.read",
```

NEW LOGIN payload

```js
    issuer: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/7xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxd5/v2.0',
    clientId: '83xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxbb',
    redirectUrl: 'msauth.com.application.redirect://auth/',
    additionalParameters: { prompt: 'login' },
    scopes: [
        'openid',
        'profile',
        'email',
        'offline_access',
        'Sites.ReadWrite.All' // <------ Added this in my scope
        'api://8xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxb/application.read', //audience scope
    ],
    androidAllowCustomBrowsers: ['chrome'],
```

NEW JWT Token decode

```
"aud": "0000xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx00000",
"scp": "email openid profile SharePointTenantSettings.Read.All Sites.Read.All Sites.ReadWrite.All User.Read",
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put `'api://8xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxb/application.read'` before `'Sites.ReadWrite.All'` then you would find the JWT token had scope `"scp": "application.read",`. But you put `'Sites.ReadWrite.All'` before `'api://8xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxb/application.read'`, so you got scope `...SharePointTenantSettings.Read.All Sites.Read.All...`

This is because an access token could only contain one kind of API permission.

`'Sites.ReadWrite.All'` is a short for `https://graph.microsoft.com/Sites.ReadWrite.All`, the `aud` is ms graph api, but the `aud` for your custom API `application.read` is `api://8xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxb`.